# I was solving SPOJ problem 2 of PRIME GENERATOR. I am getting wrong answer as output by SPOJ compiler. Can someone help me?

Tags: java

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers!

Input
The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

Output
For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

Example

Input:
2

1  10

3  5

Output:

2

3

5

7

//----------BLANK SPACE BETWEEN TEST CASES-------------

3

5

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
     public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        boolean prime = true;
        long m = in.nextLong();
        long n = in.nextLong();
        if(m<2)
        {
            System.out.println("2");
            m=3;
        }
        for(int j=m;j<=n;j+=2)
        {
            int z = (int)Math.floor(Math.sqrt(j));
            for(int k=2;k<=z;k++)
            {
                if(j%k==0)
                {
                    prime=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(prime)
                System.out.println(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops are using `int` datatype. It is lossy because you are comparing `long` with `int`. It will work for small numbers but constraints are too big so try using `long`.

#### Edit

I thought its because overflow without running it.

Your code has lots of problems

- It will not work when m is even
- you are not setting `prime` back to `true` in loop

Check these suggestions and comment is it working?

Solution

- use `long` datatype in loop (that is not necessary)
- set `prime = true` in inner loop
- instead of incrementing by 2 i.e. `j+=2`, increment by 1 `j+=1`.